# Shipping in Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento1.9.2.3, shipping-tax

I'm newbie, with low expertise in Magento. The shipping extension I use is provided by the shipping company. I work with and installed by them. The price calculated in the front end doubles the shipping cost. May it be due to the fact that also in the `Sales section - Tax - Product tax classes` I have the class Shipping? Should I delete this class, once I have the module installed by the shipment company?

Comment: Have you try to install extesion into another fresh magento and check, does the same issue comes or not?

Comment: No, I didn't. Thank you. I'm sure I set something wrong. I'll try. Thanks again.